# Windows 10 universal XmlNode does not contain a definition for SelectSingleNode

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio

Using Windows 10 Visual Studios C#. I am trying to read from an XML file and I have read through the assembly documentation:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode(v=vs.110).aspx

The documentation clearly says that 'SelectSingleNode' and 'SelectNodes' are available methods but they don't appear in the predictive list and when trying to use them I get the error message 'XmlNode does not contain a definition for SelectSingleNode'.

I have been searching for a solution to this for a while and I can't seem to find a solution.

(yes, I have included System.Xml and I even tried using the sample code from MS and it produces the same problem)

Comment: What kind of application are you trying to build with Visual Studio and C#?

Comment: You're probably looking at the wrong docs.  Check the assembly and full name of the type you're working with in the application.  Alternatively, these are extension methods in a different namespace.

Comment: Is the [overload with the `XmlNamespaceManager`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0hw012b%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) present?

Answer (score 4):

I am currently running into the same issue, but have started to find some information.
From what I understand about UWP you will need to use XDocument and LINQ, part of the namespace:
System.Xml.Linq

[MSDN reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument(v=vs.110).aspx)

A code snippet of linq example:

```
XDocument loadedData = XDocument.Load(XMLPath);
var data = from query in loadedData.Descendants("Order")                      
   select new Countries
   {
       OrderId  = (string)query.Attribute("OrderID") ,
       OrderTotal = (string)query.Attribute("OrderTotal"),
       Customer = (string)query.Attribute("Customer"),
       Phone = (string)query.Attribute("Phone")
   };
DataGrid1.ItemsSource = data;
```

This has been the best solution I have found to the same question.

Comment: I have lost 2 rep points for this post. It has been down voted with -1. There use to be a comment giving advice on the post to improve it. I compied and improved it. Yet, I still lost points and had 20 votes to delete this post.
None of those voters have commented or shown what is incorrect with this answer. 
As a general comment this makes the desire to participate in the community very low.

Comment: Not sure why your answer was downvoted, it works for me, thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

It is possible you are looking at the System.Xml versions still, which when referenced, do not bring in those methods.

If you rename your System.Xml to Windows.Data.Xml.Dom (namespace), then you won't have XmlNode anymore. It's now IXmlNode. This interface has the SelectSingleNode and SelectNodes you want.