# The error of there is no method of selectsinglenode in System.xml while compiling a Hololens app using Unity 3D

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine, hololens

```
Error CS1061: 'XmlDocument' does not contain a definition for 'SelectSingleNode' and no 
extension method 'SelectSingleNode' accepting a first argument of type 'XmlDocument' 
could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

I am a newer on .net,a strange error happened,the error code was as follow:

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.Load(fp);      
XmlNodeList nodelist = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("samples").ChildNodes;
```

And the code run ok when I chick the play of Unity,and error when I build to Hololens. Maybe it's because the version of .Net differs between Unity and UWP.

The .net is 3.5 ,and System.Xml is 2.0.0
So how can I solve this problem?I searched on Net, someone suggested to add package reference,how to add?

Comment: Unity and UWP use different .NET version. This is documented here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/gaming/missing-dot-net-apis-in-unity-and-uwp and there are similar questions to yours https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32314982/windows-10-universal-xmlnode-does-not-contain-a-definition-for-selectsinglenode

Comment: I have viewed that question and document.And I used the method ```GetElementByTagname``` to place the ```SelectSingleNode```,But I still have no idea how to use ```SelectSingleNode``` method.

Comment: Did you consider using Unity's [XmlSerializer](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/Saving_and_Loading_Data:_XmlSerializer)?